# C# Wii Mote Gesture Recognition

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages, wiimote, wii

Are there any C# gesture recognition libraries available for Wii Mote (Wii Remote) ?

**Update**
Found one library for gesture recognition. Need to test and see about the accuracy.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wiimotion/

**Another Update**
Found Another Library
http://gesturelib.codeplex.com/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at Johnny Lee's website:

http://johnnylee.net/projects/wii/

He did a remarkable demo thats very famous: [Head Tracking for Desktop VR Displays using the WiiRemote](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd3-eiid-Uw)

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Managed-Library-for-Nintendos-Wiimote

Comment: Hi,
I'm already using this library, but now i'm searching for a library which can record and recognize gestures.
Just found one http://sourceforge.net/projects/wiimotion/. Need to test and see.
Thanx for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can read this one [Managed-Library-for-Nintendos-Wiimote](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Managed-Library-for-Nintendos-Wiimote) there you ll see example

Comment: Hi,
I'm already using this library, but now i'm searching for a library which can record and recognize gestures.
Just found one http://sourceforge.net/projects/wiimotion/. Need to test and see.
Thanx for the answer anyway :)

Comment: Ok so download this example, there (i hope) you will find all what you want. http://sourceforge.net/projects/wiimotebowling/files/

Answer (score 1):

There is a Wii-Mote managed library for .NET  [here](http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/)

There is currently no documentation so you might have to find some example source code and learn from that.

Comment: Hi,
I'm already using this library, but now i'm searching for a library which can record and recognize gestures.
Just found one http://sourceforge.net/projects/wiimotion/. Need to test and see.
Thanx for the answer anyway :)